# Show 7 integers along with how far each one is from an average

Tags: c#

I can't seem to figure out how to show the values and how far each value is from the average. Here is the code I have, but I know it's not correct. I've been trying everything to just get it close to what it wants.

This is homework for an online class so not a lot of options for help. Thanks for any input!

```
int[] temp = new int[7];
        int x;
        string daysString;
        for (x = 0; x < temp.Length; ++x)
        {
            Write("Enter the high temperature for the day: ");
            daysString = ReadLine();
            temp[x] = Convert.ToInt32(daysString);
        }
        WriteLine("\n-----------------------------------------");
        WriteLine("The high temperature for each of the 7 days you entered: ");
        for (x = 0; x < temp.Length; ++x)
            Write("{0, 6}", temp[x]);

        //Step 3. Compute Average
        double average = temp.Average();
        WriteLine("");
        WriteLine("\n-----------------------------------------");
        WriteLine("Average = {0}", average);

        //Step 4. Find out how many numbers in the array are greater than the average. 
        int count = 0;
        foreach (int i in temp)
        {
            if (i > average) count++;
        }
        Write("\n----------------------------------------------");
        WriteLine("");
        WriteLine("How many days away each high temperature is from the average");
        WriteLine("{0, 6}", count);
```

Comment: You havent mentioned the problem, _"I know it's not correct"_ is not sufficient. Step 4 doesn't seem to be the problem,

Comment: Please read [MCVE] guidance on posting code. "It is not correct" is very poor explanation of the problem.

Comment: I can get the average but the bottom portion of code is only showing one number not 7.

Comment: @JenniferLopez: the bottom portion(step 4) is doing something completely different

Comment: int count = 0;
        foreach (int i in temp)
        {
            if (i > average) count++;
        }
        Write("\n----------------------------------------------");
        WriteLine("");
        WriteLine("How many days away each high temperature is from the average");
        WriteLine("{0, 6}", count);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last step 4 does something different, what you actually want is:

> how far are all 7 temperatures away from the average?

```
int[] distancesFromAverage = temp
    .Select(temperature => (int)Math.Abs(temperature - average))
    .ToArray();
```

Now you can output the temperature and the distance to the average:

```
for(int i = 0; i < temp.Length; i++)
    Console.WriteLine($"Temperature: {temp[i]} Distance from average: {distancesFromAverage[i]}");
```

Comment: Thanks! The code is working now closer to what the answer is wanting. Now I just need to have the average days away not come up with decimal places and be negative numbers.

Comment: Use Math.Abs to get positive value and cast to int. I have edited the answer

Comment: If you want a rounded value put the Math.Abs call in a Math.Round

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't understand the question

> how far each value is from the average

but since you already computed the average

```
foreach (int val in temp)
{
    WriteLine(val - average);
}
```

would tell you the difference between your value and the average...

If you have an out-of-the list base-value as suggested in the comment and want to know how many days after that value you currently are

```
for (int i=0; i<temp.Length; i++)
{
    WriteLine ($"The value {temp[i]} is {i+1} days after the average");
}
```

The average is a value not neccesarily contained in the list (the average of 3, 5 and 8 is 6, which is not part of the list) so you can't really tell how many days a value is after the average. Or are you looking for the median instead of the average? Then you can sort the list, take the middle value and then look for the distance to that specific value.

Comment: Here is the whole question: A program that accepts seven int values representing high temperatures for seven consecutive days. Display each of the values along with a message that indicates how far it is from the average. At first I thought it just wanted how far away the temperatures were from the average but now I see that it wants each temperature output to have how far away it is from the average. And that's where I am confused on what to do and make that work.

Comment: so if day zero is the average day and the array contains the outliers then WriteLine ($"The value {temp[i]} is {i+1} days after the average"); would do that? (this requires a regular for-loop and not a foreach)

Comment: Thank you for your help!